Probability space in survival analysis - Formal framework
I'm struggling to picture the formal framework in survival analysis.
Survival analysis consists (very roughly) on estimating the time taken by a phenomenon to happen (the archetypical example being the death of an organism).
The main object of study is the survival function $S(t)$, which provides the probability that the organism will survive.
Now, formally, one considers a random variable $T$ on a probability space $(\Omega,p)$ and defines
$$
S(t) = p(T>t).
$$
Whereas this function always exists (as far as I know), most of the examples I've seen consider smooth functions $S(t)$.
The problem of that assumption is that $T$ must be a continuous random variable.
I say that this is a problem because I would think that the probability space on which $T$ is defined is the discrete space $\Omega=\{0,1\}$, with probability $p_0 = p(0)$ and $p_1=p(1)$, corresponding to whether the event happened or not.
What is the correct probability space (and why is it not $\{0,1\}$)?
Thanks

I am assuming by $X$ you mean $T$? In fact, in survival analysis $T$ usually denotes a random variable in time. I.e. $S(t)$ is the probability that the event time (or time of death in the classical case) is later than some given time $t$. In this framework $T$ is of course continuous.

@LSK21 Oops! Good catch. But a random variable is a measurable function $X:\Omega\to \Psi$. I'm happy to accept that in this case $\Psi =\mathbb R$ with the Lebesgue measure. But what about the probability space $\Omega$? As the space of events, I don't see how it could be different from ${0,1}$ (died/survived). Thefore $T$ would be actually discrete. I mean, yes, one can still consider $S(t)$ as a function of time, but it won't definitely be smooth

True, you did ask about $\Omega$, my mistake. However, I don't think it is as simple as $\Omega = {0, 1}$. In fact, I think $\Omega$ should contain all possible factors contributing to some survival time, in which case it makes more sense to just keep it as an abstract set. For example, an event could be $\omega = $ {Person smokes, person does not eat red meat}. Either way, $T$ would be considered continuous if the values it takes are continuous, not if the event space is non-discrete.

@LSK21 I must admit I do struggle picturing sample spaces in general, not only in survival analysis. And it seems that in statistics it's common to consider random variables without specifying the sample space, which is bothering me a lot at the moment.  Regarding the last sentence of your comment, I agree, but $T$ can't be continuous if the sample space is discrete, right?

But as far as I know, $\Omega$ represents the set of all outcomes of the experiment. I don't see how in this particular case there can be more than 2 outcomes...

I agree that it can be a bit hand-wavey sometimes. What is usually meant in statistics with a continuous random variable is that the values it can take are "continuous" in the sense that there is "no space between them." In other words, its distribution function would be continuous. I think there are cases (perhaps look up mixed distributions) where the sample space is discrete and the random variable is considered continuous.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In my opinion your are mistaken on the meaning of $T$ and it explain your confusion on $\Omega$.
Since you define the survival function by: $S(t) =p(T>t)$ it means that the random varibale $T$ does not represent that the phenomenon happened or not but at which time it occured.
Thus if you sample your random variable and obtain $T=t$, it means that the death occured at time $t$.
Hence in your case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^+$ (or whatever your time is measured in).
I hope my answer is clear enough.
EDIT:
To be clearer (english is not my first language sorry) I will try to use the wikipedia terms.
The sample space $\Omega$ is not whether the phenomenon ocurred or not but the date at which it occured
The event space is $\sigma$-algebra representing the measurable sets of the sample space. In you example $T$ greater than a value is measurable set.
Hopping that it somehow clarify the answer

I guess your right. I was thinking of $\Omega$ as the outcomes of the ''measure'' go check if the organism is alive or not,.  But I think $\Omega$ should be as you describe and the $T$ will be just the identity. I'll leave the question open to see if someone else wants to post another answer. Otherwise you'll get the bounty
